# Can I set up my safari extension to be installed when clicked instead of downloaded?

Tags: safari, safari-extension, browser-addons

I have written, signed, and built a safari extension (.safariextz file). I have tried adding two mime type handlers to apache:

```
AddType application/x-safari-extension .safariextz
```

and also i have tried

```
AddType application/octet-stream .safariextz
```

When I click on the link to the extension it downloads, but it does not "install"

Is it possible for me to host the extension on my web server and have it prompt to install the extension when clicked in a similar fashion to how chrome or firefox extensions prompt you to install them - or is this possibly only from the apple extension site?

Answer (score 1):

We are looking into this as well.  So far it seems that you can only do a one-click install via Apple Extension Site.  The answers here seem to definitively state that: [One Click install for Safari Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375154/one-click-install-for-safari-extensions)